# How to apply css to ng-repeat elements based on the value of a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

Say, if I want to change the color of an ng-repeat element when a certain condition is satisfied. I tried using element.css, but that changes the color of all the elements in ng-repeat.

```
<body ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="dayController">
        <h3 ng-repeat="day in days" highlight="{{ day }}">
            {{ day }}
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my controller and directive :

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

// Controller
app.controller('dayController', function($scope){
    $scope.days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    $scope.today = $scope.days[new Date().getDay()];
    $scope.tomorrow = $scope.days[(new Date().getDay() + 1) % 7];
});

// Directive
app.directive("highlight", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.today == attrs["highlight"]) {
            // Change the color of that day
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a directive to achieve such simple stuff. Just use `ng-class` and you will be fine:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h3 ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{'highlight-today': day === today }">
    {{ day }}
  </h3>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.highlight-today {
  background-color: red;
}
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  $scope.today = $scope.days[new Date().getDay()];
  $scope.tomorrow = $scope.days[(new Date().getDay() + 1) % 7];
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c8h4bz6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just add `element.css('background-color', 'yellow');` inside the if condition.

here is the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

      // Controller
      app.controller('dayController', function($scope) {
        $scope.days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
        $scope.today = $scope.days[new Date().getDay()];
        $scope.tomorrow = $scope.days[(new Date().getDay() + 1) % 7];
      });

      // Directive
      app.directive("highlight", function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (scope.today == attrs["highlight"]) {
            // Change the color of that day
            element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
          }
        }
      });
    }());
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="dayController">
    <h3 ng-repeat="day in days" highlight="{{ day }}">
            {{ day }}
        </h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```